# Why do I get the error message when reading from a FIFO?

Tags: linux, server, client, fifo

On the Introduction to Operative Systems course we're asked to build a client-server model using FIFOs. As client we send a string to the server, the server gets this string and if a file with this name exists it sends back the first line on this file. If the file doesn't exist or it does exist but it happens to be empty, it sends an empty string back.

The problem is that in only works once, i send file1 for example, the server sends back the first line and when I send again file1 or another file's name in the same "session" the `printf("First line of the file %s: \n%s\n", name, recived);` doesn't happen, it enters into `if (read(fifo_serv_client, recived, sizeof(recived)) == -1) { printf("An error occurred.\n"); }`.

Any idea on why is this? I tried doing it two times with the same file, so it exists 100% but I still get the same result.

Thank you so much!

Here is the code for the client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFSIZE 512

int main()
{
   int fifo_client_serv;
   char *fifo1 = "fifo_client_serv";

   int fifo_serv_client;
   char *fifo2 = "fifo_serv_client";

   char name[BUFSIZE];

   while(1) {
      printf("Write the file's name: ");
      scanf("%s", name);

      /* write str to the FIFO */
      fifo_client_serv = open(fifo1, O_WRONLY);
      fifo_serv_client = open(fifo2, O_RDONLY);
      write(fifo_client_serv, name, sizeof(name));

      char recived[BUFSIZE];

      if (read(fifo_serv_client, recived, sizeof(recived)) == -1) {
         printf("An error occurred.\n");
      } else {
         printf("First line of the file %s: \n%s\n", name, recived);
         close(fifo_client_serv);
         close(fifo_serv_client);

      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

And here's the code for the server:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define BUFSIZE 512

int main()
{
   int fifo_client_serv;
   char *fifo1 = "fifo_client_serv";

   int fifo_serv_client;
   char *fifo2 = "fifo_serv_client";

   char buf[BUFSIZE];
   char line[BUFSIZE];

   FILE *file;

   /* create the FIFO (named pipe) */
   mkfifo(fifo1, 0777);
   mkfifo(fifo2, 0777);
   
   printf("Server runnning...\n");

   while (1)
   {
      fifo_client_serv = open(fifo1, O_RDONLY);
      fifo_serv_client = open(fifo2, O_WRONLY);
      read(fifo_client_serv, buf, BUFSIZE); 
       
      if((file = fopen(buf, "r")) == NULL) {
         write(fifo_serv_client, "", BUFSIZE);
      } else {
         fgets(line, BUFSIZE, file);
         write(fifo_serv_client, line, BUFSIZE);
      }

      /* clear buffer and line */
      memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));
      memset(line, 0, sizeof(buf));

      close(fifo_client_serv);
      close(fifo_serv_client);

      unlink(fifo1);
      unlink(fifo2);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE** I found why this happens, if I create the fifo inside the while it works fine! I just put `mkfifo(fifo1, 0777); mkfifo(fifo2, 0777);` first in the while. My question is, is it really necessary to create the FIFO each time I send a text from the client? Can't I just create once the FIFO, do the communication from it and close once I finish?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to close the file after read/writes in the server file ?

```
if((file = fopen(buf, "r")) == NULL) {
     write(fifo_serv_client, "", BUFSIZE);
     fclose(file);
} else {     
     fgets(line, BUFSIZE, file);
     write(fifo_serv_client, line, BUFSIZE);
     fclose(file);
}
```

By the way. Its worth to do error checking on your `writes`.

Comment: Still happens the same, I error checked every write in both the cllient and the server and when I input for the second time a name the `write(fifo_client_serv, name, sizeof(name));`